# Flutter, Bloc, why only Stream used in MapEventToState

Tags: flutter, bloc

I looked up a lot of bloc examples, but they all used only streams like below.

```
@override
  Stream<SomeModel> mapEventToState(SomeEvent event) async* {
    if (event is A event) {
       //yield* calling stream function..    
    } else if (event is B event) {
       //yield calling stream function..    

       //I have never seen a calling future function here. 
       //Even if it exists, it exists in this stream function, like in a nested form.
    }
```

So I wonder why only streams are used.

Also, if there are many streams, will there be a side effect of memory overload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Reactive Programming — Streams — BLoC](https://medium.com/flutter-community/reactive-programming-streams-bloc-6f0d2bd2d248) article for the best example and explanation about streams and the impacts of using them.